# click event using jqTransform

Tags: jquery, click, jqtransform

How can I get selected value from a jqTransform select box?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').jqTransform();

$(document).on("click", ".jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a", function()
{
    alert("ok");
});
```

The sample code above is not firing and I don't kown why :(

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matias/ghFdC/

**EDIT 1:** I should point out that the select box is added dynamically and then I apply the plugin, hence the `.on()`

**EDIT 2**: I prefer the use of `.on()` instead of `.bind()`. From jQuery: "*As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case is with jquery.jqtransform.js, in the line 273 this use:

```
$ul.find('a').click(function(){
```

and in the end use *return false*, then this call by jquery to

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

and then stop there...

Apparently this stop the delegate *on*, but that doesnt happen with this:

```
$('form').jqTransform();
$('.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').bind('click',function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

if you preffer you can remove that *return false* (jquery.jqtransform.js) and i think *on* will work

Comment: I should point out that the select box is added dynamically and then I apply the plugin, hence the .on()

Comment: Thanks for your time! but, do you know why .on() isn't working?